# Removing Multiple Characters from a String Using Stringr

Tags: regex, r, tidyr, stringr

I'm fairly new to working with strings in R. Below is a simple dataframe with a variety of different inputs for phone numbers, including some entries with no numbers at all and just brackets or hyphens. I'm looking for a way to convert all the numbers to 9999999999. So basically I want to remove all the non-numeric symbols and spaces. Entries without numbers will just become empty cells.

Is there an easy way to do this with gsub or by using Stringr or Tidyr? I'm not sure if the solution requires a regular expression.

```
names<-c("Mike","James","Melissa","Chris","John","Jake")

numbers<-c("(999)-999-9999","999-999-9999","(999) 999-9999","(999)-999 9999","(   )","    -")

Names2<-data.frame(numbers,names)

Names2$numbers<-as.character(Names2$numbers)
```

Comment: regex is your friend - `gsub("[^0-9]", "", Names2$numbers)`

Comment: Thanks, so simple and elegant. One quick question, how do I fill the empty cells with NA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
Names2$numbers <- gsub("\\D+", "", Names2$numbers)
as.numeric(Names2$numbers)
#[1] 9999999999 9999999999 9999999999 9999999999         NA         NA
```

As the OP mentioned about `string`,

```
library(stringr)
as.numeric(str_replace_all(Names2$numbers, "\\D+", ""))
#[1] 9999999999 9999999999 9999999999 9999999999         NA         NA
```